# What kind of adhesive should I use to secure a concrete paver stone step?

Tags: concrete, masonry, stone, pavers, walkway

I have a concrete paver stone that has come loose. It is used as a ‘step’ from one area of lower paver walkway to a higher area. I’ve included a picture of the area where the stone became loose.

I don’t know what kind of adhesive to use to secure this single 30-40lb ledge paver step. I live in a fairly humid climate and the front walkway sees significant moisture and rain throughout the year.

Image:
https://ibb.co/6bFr3bH

Any ideas? It needs to be able to withstand the weight of people walking over it and rain and snow.

Thanks!

Comment: where do you live?  If you are in an area where freeze and thaw are an issue the choices of a bonding agent are different.

Comment: I live in PA where there is a lot of freeze thaw over the winter and in an area that receives significant rainfall throughout the year. I saw the other answer with loctite. I thought about using that but I saw it says not for step construction. Im not sure if I need epoxy, mortar, or another type of adhesive like loctite. I want to do it the right way if possible.

Comment: Your best bet is epoxy. I used to live in Pa. the winters were brutal.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an epoxy recommendation?

Comment: If you only have one stone, use some JB weld for masonry.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results with Loctite PL500 Landscape Block Adhesive.  But this is by no means the only option on the market.  So this or something similar should do the job for you.

[Loctite PL500 Landscape Block Adhesive](https://www.loctiteproducts.com/en/products/build/construction-adhesives/pl-pro-line/loctite_pl_500_landscapeblockadhesive.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use fast set concrete, it will last much longer than the glue and is much cheaper